# How to re-add deleted files as result of backout operation in Perfroce?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I had submitted a change-list containing some new files and then for some reason had to back-out.

Now I am trying to submit a new change-list that adds the same file back.

The problem is that when I backed-out, it deleted those files from HEAD revision and now when I am trying to submit my change-list it says 'Out of date files must be resolved or reverted'

I tried googling the solution but could not find anything relevant, can somebody please guide me right direction?

Comment: What happens when you try to resolve the file(s) named in the error message?  Maybe somebody else already re-added the file underneath you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to back out the first back-out. (When you say you backed out the addition, you mean you also submitted it, right?)

Locate the changelist that you submitted, e.g. via P4V's *Submitted* tab, right-click and choose *Back Out...*.

It's best if the files you're trying to resurrect (re-add) don't already exist on your filesystem, otherwise Perforce will refuse to overwrite them. (Which may be what the error message is telling you; I'm not sure.)